# R Bookdown: access auto-generated date in meta tag

Tags: javascript, html, r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using the bookdown package in R to publish a nicely looking "book" online. I want to include the date that the book was last generated into the `footer.html`, so that this is visible on each page of the book. I've searched for an answer many times, but no solution that I've found has worked so far, and I don't know whether this is due to my limited knowledge of HTML/JS or due to peculiarities in the bookdown package.

### Content of my current files:

Most important yml fields in `index.Rmd` (located in the root of my project folder, following [bookdown's guidance](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/update-date.html)):

```html
--- 
title: "Title of book"
author: "Author of book"
date: 'r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B %Y")'
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
description: |
  Some description
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
    toc_float: true
---
```

Most important content in `_output.yml` (also located in the root of my project folder, see [Rmd guidance](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#includes)):

```html
bookdown::gitbook:
  split_by: section
  css: assets/style.css
  includes:
    in_header: assets/header.html
    after_body: assets/footer.html # The footer is loaded on each page
```

Simplification of `footer.html`, located in the `assets` folder in my project:

```html
<div class = "footer">
  <footer>
    <small>
      Last updated: 
      <!-- This does not work: results in "undefined" -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var date = document.querySelector('meta[name="date"]').content;
        document.write(date);
      </script>
    </small>
  </footer>
</div>
```

### The problem

I want to access the `date` variable that was created in the `index.Rmd` yaml. Through Inspect on the published web page, it looks like `date` is written into the metadata of the site as it says:
`<meta name = "date" content = "2022-08-08"> == $0`. Therefore, I assumed that I should access the date via the head metadata.

I've tried to use some javascript to extract the "date" metadata from the head (see the footer.html content I pasted above). Strangely, I *can* access other metadata, such as the description and author. These are also defined in the yaml in `index.Rmd`. But all of these other fields I can access, just not the date (results in "undefined"). What am I doing wrong? Is there another way I can (set and) access the `date` in `index.Rmd`?

### Update

After regenerating the documents, `date` is not even in the metadata anymore, whereas other fields from the `index.Rmd` are (e.g., author, description, github-repo). **Why is date the only variable from `index.Rmd` that is not written in the metadata?** Is this a bookdown issue?

Here's a copy of the  content (NB *without*  `<link>`s to stylesheets):

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Title of book</title>
  <meta name="description" content="<p>Some description</p>" />
  <meta name="generator" content="bookdown 0.28 and GitBook 2.6.7" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Title of book" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="book" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="image.png" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="<p>Some description</p>" />
  <meta name="github-repo" content="account/repo" />
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Title of book" />
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="<p>Some description</p>" />
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="img.png" />
  <meta name="author" content="Author of book" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <script src="libs/jquery-3.6.0/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fuse.js@6.4.6/dist/fuse.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/accessible-code-block-0.0.1/empty-anchor.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/anchor-sections-1.1.0/anchor-sections.js"></script>
  <script src="book.js"></script>
</head>
```